# AndroidStudio VM shutdown myapp becaouse of setText method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    public void save(View view)
    {
        if (!editText.getText().toString().matches(""))
        {
            int userAge = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            textView.setText(""+userAge);
        }
    }
```

this code work with VM but if i change part of

```
textView.setText(""+userAge);
```

this to this

```
textView.setText(userAge);
```

onclick method shutdown app on VM both code work same goal, but i don't understand why second row doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `setText` with integer inside. You first need to convert it to a string.
There is two options, `textView.setText(""+userAge);`, `textView.setText(String.valueOf(userAge));`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an int as a string. You have to use .ToString(), or adding the string before, as you did at the first row.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView.setText(int)` will set the text to a resource ID corresponding to a string resource defined in your `strings.xml`. Here, when you do `textView.setText(userAge)`, you are calling this method, but `userAge` is not a valid string resource ID, so it crashes.

However, when you do `TextView.setText(""+userAge)`, you are converting the int to a String, just not in a conventional way. Concatenating anything to a string implicitly calls `.toString()` on the object, and `String.valueOf` for primitives. But instead of `TextView.setText(""+userAge)`, you can do `TextView.setText(String.valueOf(userAge))`, which is cleaner.